# Files sometimes being overwritten despite check to prevent it

Tags: java, file, nio

I have a code to work with some file:

```java
Path path = ...;
if (!path.toFile().exists() || Files.size(path) == 0L) {
  Files.write(path, data, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
}
```

It's working fine almost always, but in some cases it overrides existing file, so I'm getting corrupted file with old data overriden with new data. For example if file content was `00000000000000` and `data` is `AAA` in code above, I'll get the file with content `AAA00000000000`.
File access is syncronized well, so only one thread can access the file, only one instance of application can be started at same time. Application is running on Heroku (it's heroku-managed filesystem), I can't reproduce same behavior on my laptop.

Is it pissible that `Files.size(path)` returns zero for file with some data? How to rewrite this code to make it work correctly? Is it possible to use another `StandardOpenOption` flags to fail (throw exception) if file is not empty or doesn't exist?

Comment: Just to note, you can use [`Files.notExists(Path,LinkOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)).

Comment: “File access is syncronized well” I’m not entirely confident that it is.  Files.write doesn’t do a partial overwrite, so your result suggests another thread or process wrote to the file.  And a file can sometimes have a size of zero if another thread or process has the file open and hasn’t flushed its write, especially on Windows.

Comment: java.nio.Files.move() executes and AtomicLock (on POSIX). If you rename/move the file adding a .lock suffix (for example), the files will be always owned by just a thread and your condition will be easy; if a file doesn't end in .lock, then it's mine (and the first thing I do is renaming it)

Answer (score 0):

What is the desired behavior for an existing file with data?

1. Discard existing data

   You can use CREATE and TRUNCATE_EXISTING together.  Actually, maybe you should use nothing, since the default for write() is CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, WRITE, per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)).
2. Keep existing data

   You can open it in APPEND mode rather than WRITE mode.
3. Do nothing if file already exists and is not empty.

   This is tricky. The non-zero size report is troubling. I'd suggest using CREATE_NEW (fail if exists) and if you get the failure exception, read the file to see if it's non-empty.

Comment: According to the OP's code, the file should be written to if the file doesn't exist _**or if it has a size of `0`**_. Using `CREATE_NEW` will fail when the file exists but is empty.

Comment: True, I have given the converse behavior. I can't explain why length is returned as zero but there seems to be data in the file.  I'd imagine it is something to do with the particular file system rather than Java.  However, my update (TRUNCATE_EXISTING) seems like a preferable option.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a race hazard because it performs a "look before you leap" that can not be relied upon. In between your predicate

```
!path.toFile().exists() || Files.size(path) == 0L
```

giving `true`, which you **think** means the file has no previous content, and executing the `Files.write` to write to the file, a *different* process (or thread) could have written to the file.